# Unix timestamp date difference

Tags: mysql

I have the following timestamp:  `1449118800`. I have a table with a `last_modified` column that have data such as `01/24/2016`. What I'm looking for is the query which gets all records which are newer than the timestamp.

My query so far is:

```
select * from jobs where last_modified > DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1449118800), '%e %b %Y')`
```

It doesn't seem to be working properly as I'm getting results in 2003.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Which type is the `last_modified` column?

Comment: Are you using DATE/DATETIME for last_modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `last_modified` as '`date/datetime`'. And store 01/24/2016 as 
2016-01-24 00:00:00/2016-01-24

Then following will work

```
SELECT *
FROM `jobs`
WHERE `last_modified` > FROM_UNIXTIME( 1449118800 )
```

if `last_modified` of varchar, then try

```
SELECT *
FROM `jobs`
WHERE  str_to_date(`last_modified`, '%m/%d/%Y')  > FROM_UNIXTIME( 1449118800 )
```

Comment: cant do that its a migration

Comment: then convert using "str_to_date( `last_modified` , '%m/%d/%Y' )"

Comment: i have updated my answer for varchar. this may work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from jobs where last_modified > FROM_UNIXTIME(1449118800)
```